# Laravel remove item in collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-5.6

I am trying to remove an item inside my collection, I am trying to check wether a specific value of the current collection item is equal to the next collection item and remove the next if it is equal.

```
    $path = CanvasPath::where('stream_id', $streamId)->get();

    // if in collection $path a value ->path is identical to previous or before remove it
    foreach($path as $key => $value) {
        $collection = $path->getIterator();
        $current = current($collection);
        $next = next($collection);

        if($current->path == $next->path) {
            // remove $next collection
        }
    }
```

How can I delete that item?

Comment: Why don't you apply unique collection on it?

Comment: @Rahul hmm how would you do that?

Comment: you want distinct path from `CanvasPath` ??

Answer (score 0):

do the unique

```
$path = CanvasPath::where('stream_id', $streamId)->get();

$path = $path->map(function ($array) {
    return collect($array)->unique('id')->all();
});
```